# How do user-space programs interact with a USB 802.11 Wi-Fi driver on Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, wifi, driver

Allow me to qualify this question by stating that I am new to driver development.  I am trying to understand the driver source code for a USB Wi-Fi card that uses a RealTek 8187L chip.  Based on a good answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661679/where-in-the-linux-source-does-recognition-of-specific-usb-devices-happen), I established that the relevant driver source code that I needed to inspect is in `drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/dev.c` (inside the Linux kernel source).

Doing some reading, it seems as though a USB driver instantiates a `usb_driver` struct that it registers with the kernel, which describes (among other things) the devices the driver supports (`.id_table`), the function to execute when a supported device is connected (`.probe`) and *optionally*, a set of file operations (`.fops`), for interaction with user-space.  The `usb_driver` struct associated with the 8187L driver does *not* include a `.fops`:

```
static struct usb_driver rtl8187_driver = {
    .name       = KBUILD_MODNAME,
    .id_table   = rtl8187_table,
    .probe      = rtl8187_probe,
    .disconnect = __devexit_p(rtl8187_disconnect),
    .disable_hub_initiated_lpm = 1,
};

module_usb_driver(rtl8187_driver);
```

Hence, I am curious as to how user-space programs are interacting with this driver to send and receive data.

On an [old Linux Journal post](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4786) (2001), there is the following excerpt:

> The fops and minor variables are optional. Most USB drivers hook into another kernel
>       subsystem, such as the SCSI, network or TTY subsystem. These types of drivers register 
>       themselves with the other kernel subsystem, and any user-space interactions are provided 
>       through that interface. But for drivers that do not have a matching kernel subsystem, 
>       such as MP3 players or scanners, a method of interacting with user space is needed. The 
>       USB subsystem provides a way to register a minor device number and a set of 
>       file_operations **[fops]** function pointers that enable this user-space interaction.

So it sounds like the 8187L driver is probably one that "hooks into another kernel subsystem".  So I suppose my question is, for such a driver, which *doesn't* supply a `.fops` function pointer, *how is the interaction taking place with this other kernel subsystem*?  Ultimately I want to be able to find the point(s) in the driver code that programs are actually interacting with to send and receive data so I can continue to analyse how the code works.

Answer (score 4):

The driver for an individual wireless chipset is at a very low level. There are many layers between it and userspace. The next layer above rtl8187 is mac80211. In `drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/dev.c` observe the call to `ieee80211_register_hw`. That registration call provides the link between the mac80211 layer and the rtl8187 device.

Next look at the implementation of `ieee80211_register_hw`, found in `net/mac80211/main.c`. That calls `ieee80211_if_add`, found in `net/mac80211/iface.c`, which calls `register_netdevice`. And that puts the device in the kernel's main list of network interfaces, making it available for things like `ifconfig` and `route`.

Most userspace programs don't interact directly with a network interface, they just send packets to an IP address and the kernel uses the routing table to choose an outgoing interface.

Comment: How about a program like `airmon-ng` that puts a Wi-Fi card into monitor mode, or using `iwconfig` to change the Wi-Fi channel?  I don't believe the Wi-Fi card is even required to have an IP address at that point.  How would a program like `airmon-ng` or `iwconfig` be interfacing with the kernel/driver to get the message to the Wi-Fi card to do some action?

Comment: They'd be using the interface name that was registered with `register_netdevice`.

Comment: Just so you know, when userspace was mentioned, my first thought was higher-level applications like ssh, ftp, firefox... the kind that don't care whether the network connection is wifi or modem or pigeon-based. Your choice of userspace examples happened to be different

Answer (score 0):

The RTL8187 driver registers itself with the IEEE 802.11 wireless networking subsystem, by [calling `ieee80211_alloc_hw()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/dev.c#L1426) [and `ieee80211_register_hw()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/dev.c#L1610) in its probe function.